# Search for list of possible values in one field

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

In kibana I want to define a query, which will find all entries containing a field `number`with either a value of `234`, `231`, `1`.

Is there a way to define a query, looking something like `number: (234, 231, 1)`(This does not work).

Currently my only working query looks like: `(number:234 OR number:231 OR number:1)`.

Answer (score 18):

Kibana uses Lucene query syntax.

You can't feed a conventional list to a field, but something like:

```
page_root:(owa OR ews OR autodiscover)
```

should work in lieu of the much more verbose

```
(page_root:owa OR page_root:ews OR page_root:autodiscover)
```

Answer (score 1):

For numeric values it does not work, but works if we quote the numbers i.e. `number: (234, 231, 1)` will not work but `number: ("234", "231", "1")` works